# Do I need to use try-catch for every command?

Tags: c#, oledb

I have oledb connection. I use try-catch because commands sometimes getting error. Like this:

```
    OleDbConnection Connection;
    Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" +
               Server.MapPath("~/db.mdb"));
    OleDbCommand Command1, Command2, Command3;

    Command1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT a FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", Connection);
    Command2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT a FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 2", Connection);
    Command3 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT a FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 3", Connection);

try
{
    Connection.Open();
    var1= (int)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
    var2= (int)Command2.ExecuteScalar();
    var3= (int)Command3.ExecuteScalar();
    Connection.Close()
}
catch (Exception)
{
var1 = 2;
var2 = 24;
var3 = 55;
}
```

But when I get error from `Command1`, its go to catch and use catch values. I need to use catch values when getting error that command. Because for example `Command2` and `Command3` working fine. Just `Command1` getting error. I can use try-catch for every command like this:

```
try
{
var1= (int)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
}
catch (Exception)
{
var1 = 2;
}
...
```

But I have 300-400 commands, I can't use try-catch for every commands(I can but so hard). How can I use catch for just getting error commands?

Comment: You'll need to catch individual exceptions where you can reasonably expect them to occur.  The compiler isn't smart enough to know that the one line that has errored isn't going to cause further problems/knock-on effects in the rest of the `try` block, so it won't run any of it.  Consider restructuring your code so it isn't a list of one command after another, perhaps with a function to run the command and return a default value if it fails etc.

Comment: Why do you need 400 different sql statements in one block?! Anyway, have you considered looping through a list of commands and just try/catch with a default value for each command (maybe using a dictionary)?

Comment: I'd rather throw my computer out the window then executing 300 sql commands like you wrote them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope for you that this code is just a demo and not your actual code.
This is a great example for how not to use databases.

A fast and simple solution to this will be to encapsulate the execution of the command with the try catch block. something like this:

```
bool TryGetInt(OleDbCommand Command, int ValueIfException, out int Value) 
{
    try
    {
        if(Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || Connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken) 
        {
          Connection.Open();
        }
         Value = (int)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
         return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         // Consider writing the exception into a log file
         Value = ValueIfException;
         return false;
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
TryGetInt(Command1, 2, out var1);
TryGetInt(Command2, 24, out var2);
....
Connection.Close();
```

Note that my suggested function returns a boolean value to indicate success.

Of course, you can create a dictionary to hold the commands with their fail values and iterate it using foreach.

### However

I must point out that you should reconsider your design. 300 database calls are **way**{300} too many database calls to make in a single website, let alone a single aspx page.

Answer (score 2):

You can just write a function that takes your command string and the catch value as a parameter and do the try/catch handling logic there.

Comment: +1'd for solving the OP's problem, but I'd strongly suggest against using this approach - it makes the application incredibly hard to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Would be useful to maybe include an example of having a unique default value for each failed try as that was one of the OPs issues

Answer (score 2):

You can create list of commands, add each command in list and then call in loop. Like this:

```
        OleDbConnection Connection;
        Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" +
                   Server.MapPath("~/db.mdb"));
        OleDbCommand Command1, Command2, Command3;

        List<OleDbCommand> commands = new List<OleDbCommand>();
        commands.Add(new OleDbCommand("SELECT a FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", Connection));
        commands.Add(new OleDbCommand("SELECT a FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 2", Connection));
        commands.Add(new OleDbCommand("SELECT a FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 3", Connection));

        Connection.Open();
        foreach (var command in commands)
        {
            try
            {
                var1= (int)Command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                  // ...
            }
        }
        Connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like the below. 2 Options given. One templated in case you are not only dealing with int. But you would suppress all Exceptions. This is generally not a good idea. Better to catch specific exceptions:

```
        OleDbCommand b = myCommand;
        int c = ExecuteScalarSuppressException(b, 24);
        int d = ExecuteScalarSuppressException<int>(b, 33);

    private static int ExecuteScalarSuppressException(OleDbCommand oleDbCommand, int defaultValue)
    {
        int returnValue = defaultValue;
        try
        {
            defaultValue = (int)oleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }

    private static T ExecuteScalarSuppressException<T>(OleDbCommand oleDbCommand, T defaultValue)
    {
        T returnValue = defaultValue;
        try
        {
            defaultValue = (T)oleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
```

Comment: Nice! +1 on the use of generics. However, I would rather return a Boolean value (and perhaps log the exception) and call it TryExecute... Swallowing exceptions is usually not such a good idea.

Comment: Thats right. But the OP was ignoring all errors so this was a quick hack. Like I posted I personally believe it is not such a good idea to catch base class Exception and ignore everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute all 300/400 commands i would rather have something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
{
   Command1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT a FROM Table1 WHERE ID = "+i, Connection);
   try{
       Connection.Open();
       var1= (int)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
   }catch(Exception e)
   {
        //your logic here
   }
}
```